# STM32 GPIO toggle speed less than expected

Tags: stm32

I have a STM32f407G Discovery Board running at 168MHZ and a Nucleo Board running at 48MHZ.
I'm learning the STM32 using CubeIDE.
All I'm doing is toggling a GPIO(LED), a unloaded GPIO pin and measuring the rates with an oscilloscope.
I would have thought toggling speed would have been in the MHZ zone but the 168MHZ board toggles at 463KHZ and the 48MHZ toggles at 200KHZ.I know that there will be some overhead so I'm not expecting full speed but I figure I must be doing something wrong or just not fully understanding.What am I missing?

outside of the code made my the IDE, this is the only code I wrote
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(Junk_GPIO_Port, Junk_Pin);
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD6_GPIO_Port,LD6_Pin);//LED

Heres the .C file

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_host.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

I2S_HandleTypeDef hi2s3;

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_I2S3_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
void MX_USB_HOST_Process(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_I2S3_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USB_HOST_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(Junk_GPIO_Port, Junk_Pin);
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD6_GPIO_Port,LD6_Pin);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    MX_USB_HOST_Process();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief I2S3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2S3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2S3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2S3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2S3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2S3_Init 1 */
  hi2s3.Instance = SPI3;
  hi2s3.Init.Mode = I2S_MODE_MASTER_TX;
  hi2s3.Init.Standard = I2S_STANDARD_PHILIPS;
  hi2s3.Init.DataFormat = I2S_DATAFORMAT_16B;
  hi2s3.Init.MCLKOutput = I2S_MCLKOUTPUT_ENABLE;
  hi2s3.Init.AudioFreq = I2S_AUDIOFREQ_96K;
  hi2s3.Init.CPOL = I2S_CPOL_LOW;
  hi2s3.Init.ClockSource = I2S_CLOCK_PLL;
  hi2s3.Init.FullDuplexMode = I2S_FULLDUPLEXMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2S_Init(&hi2s3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2S3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2S3_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SPI1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_I2C_SPI_GPIO_Port, CS_I2C_SPI_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, Junk_Pin|LD4_Pin|LD3_Pin|LD5_Pin
                          |LD6_Pin|Audio_RST_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : CS_I2C_SPI_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CS_I2C_SPI_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(CS_I2C_SPI_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PDM_OUT_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PDM_OUT_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(PDM_OUT_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : BOOT1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = BOOT1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(BOOT1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : CLK_IN_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CLK_IN_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(CLK_IN_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : Junk_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Junk_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(Junk_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LD4_Pin LD3_Pin LD5_Pin LD6_Pin
                           Audio_RST_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD4_Pin|LD3_Pin|LD5_Pin|LD6_Pin
                          |Audio_RST_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : OTG_FS_OverCurrent_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OTG_FS_OverCurrent_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(OTG_FS_OverCurrent_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : MEMS_INT2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = MEMS_INT2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(MEMS_INT2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: If you're aiming for speed, don't use the HAL. There is an `LL` (low-level) interface to the GPIO pins that will be much, much faster. (It's mostly done with macros in a header file, rather than function calls, for example.) You can configure your project to use that in the`Project Manager->Advanced settings` tab once you open your `.ioc` file.

Comment: you call MX_USB_HOST_Process(); between every GPIO toggle. Is this what you want?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out why it doesn't toggle faster, That's it. If the toggle speed sounds reasonable to you guys, then I'm fine and consider the question answered.

Comment: Turns out I was thinking about it all wrong. I was measuring to speed of the Signal toggles state (both off and on) when I should have been thinking the interrupt fires for both change of states hence it would be twice as fast. When I factor the cmu speed, the HAL overhead, it makes sense now.Thanks